# COUNT in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

So I'm looking to write an AngularJS function that performs a COUNT of how many activities each user has performed.

Ideally: What I'd like to be able to return is (by looking at the data model below):

John Wilson - 2 Deals

Robin Wilson - 3 Deals

Garry Wilson - 3 Deals & 1 Meeting

My question is, how can I conduct a count of each activity using angularJS? What I would like to is create an element that looks like:

```
<div class="countArea" ng-repeat="activity in selectedUser.activities"
{{activity.count}}
</div>
```

The code I have so far:

```
$scope.competitionDetails = {
        organisationId: 1,
        competitionId: "52eabcf0f3672",
        currentUser: 2, 
        title: "Challenge #1",
        description: "Challenge description goes here",
        end_date: "2014-03-01",
        users: [{
            id: 2,
            name: "John Wilson",
            totalPoints: 40,
            activities: [{
                id: 6431,
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                points: 20
            }]
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: "Robin Wilson",
            totalPoints: 60,
            activities: [{
                id: 6431,
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                points: 20
            }]
        }, {
            id: 1,
            name: "Garry Wilson",
            totalPoints: 140,
            activities: [{ 
                id: 6431,
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6432,
                points: 100
            }]
        }]
    };


    $scope.activities = [{
        id: 6431,
        name: "Deal",
        points: 20
    }, {
        id: 6432,
        name: "Meeting",
        points: 100
    }];
```

Comment: Did you have a question? What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: have added some more info. My question is how to build the "count" functionality.

Comment: Since length is an array; you can use `selectedUser.activities.length` to get the number of elements in the array.  You probably do not want to do that inside a loop over the array, though.

Comment: Thanks! How can I take it one step further, and get the length/Count for EACH type of activity?

Comment: @user2656127 that you would want to do in a loop.  Loop over the activities array and access the points property of each index.

Comment: Will give it a go @thescientist thanks! Should I hvae that as a seperate function and then use an ng-repeat to access that function?

Comment: @user2656127 you could ng-repeat over users (user in users), then ng-repeat over each user.activities.  I don't think you would need any custom functions, unless I am misunderstanding you.